# Interface inheritance in VB.NET: which one do I refer to in an implementation?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

I am working with Visual Basic .NET in Visual Studio 2015, and I am wondering about the following. Suppose I have two interfaces, named `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`, with `InterfaceB` inheriting from `InterfaceA` like below:

```
Public Interface InterfaceA
    Property A As String ' Type not important here.
End Interface

Public Interface InterfaceB
    Inherits InterfaceA

    Property B As Integer ' Type not important here, either.
End Interface
```

Now I am going to create a class called `InterfaceBImplementer`, which (as the name suggests) implements `InterfaceB`:

```
Public Class InterfaceBImplementer
    Implements InterfaceB

    Public Property B As Integer Implements InterfaceB.B
        Get
            ' Snip.
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            ' Snip.
        End Set
    End Property

' To be continued...
```

So far, so good. Property `B` is only found in `InterfaceB`, so there's no question of where it comes from.

However, `InterfaceB` inherits property `A` from `InterfaceA`. Both of the following implementations of `A` in `InterfaceBImplementer` appear to be valid:

```
' Referring to InterfaceA.
Public Property A As String Implements InterfaceA.A
    Get
        ' Snip.
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ' Snip.
    End Set
End Property
```

or:

```
' Referring to InterfaceB.
Public Property A As String Implements InterfaceB.A
    Get
        ' Snip.
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        ' Snip.
    End Set
End Property
```

Which one should I prefer? Is there any difference between the two, or does it not matter? What convention or best practices should I follow in this situation if the two are the same?

Comment: When you let VS do it automatically, it does Implements InterfaceA.A

Comment: My preference is with the 2nd option, `Implements InterfaceB.A`, just because it isn't otherwise clear where `InterfaceA` came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Public Property A As String Implements InterfaceB.A` since you're about to implement intefrace being cast over `InterfaceBImplementer` class.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Code which is automatically generated by Visual Studio has the form `Public Property A As String Implements InterfaceA.A`; it chooses the interface where the property is declared, not the most-derived interface.

I don't know that Visual Studio's decision here makes it the definitively better choice, but I'm sticking with the VS editor's behavior so that my code is consistent without needing to edit a bunch of auto-generated declarations.